# Организация поиска

Tags: interbase, c++

Имеется бд (interbase). И среда разработки RAD Studio C++Builder XE.

БД подключена. Приложение почти готово, но возник вопрос.

Как организовать поиск по БД? Какие компоненты нужны?

Comment: Эм, какой поиск? По БД?

Comment: Да поиск по БД.

Comment: Ну там какой-нибудь IBQuery, не?

Comment: Ну я вот и спрашиваю, что-бы мне подсказали. Может какой и IBQuery...

Comment: Ну, вбиваешь в IBQuery запрос, и получаешь что тебе нужно? Или тебе подробнее всё расписать?

Answer (score 2):

1. Выкладываете на форму компоненты: База Данных, Транзакция, Таблица, Источник данных, Грид и провязываете этот ряд справа налево через свойства.
2. Дважды щелкнув по компоненту, записываете параметры БД и Транзакции (в Транзакции поставьте ReadCommited). Содиняетесь с БД.
3. Дважды щелкнув по компоненту, выкладываете поля Таблицы и Грида в специальные окна и редактируете поля Грида так, как вам удобно.
4. Ставите Таблицу Active в true и - пожалуйста.

Comment: тема поиска не раскрыта

Comment: да это сделано, а тема поиска не раскрыта.

Comment: @Tymoteusz, для поиска изучайте SQL.

Comment: @BuilderC компоненты разместить (тем более такие как Таблица (IBTable)) Это не организация поиска...  вашим способом придется делать поиск в ПРОГРАММЕ (IBTable вернет все записи из базы и к ней надо будет применять фильтры). Правильнее будет делать это средствами базы данных, с использованием запросов или хранимых процедур.